# How to access a Codeigniter controller when the Codeigniter dir isn't in the web server's root?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I am trying to access controller`auth.php` as `http://localhost/tripsys/new_admin/auth/{whatever_function_name}`.
**Current structure:**

```
Root
└──vmt
   ├──.htaccess
   └──tripsys
      ├──.htaccess
      └──jempe
         └──application
            └─controllers
              └──new_admin
                 └──auth.php
```

**vmt/.htaccess** content:

```
Options -Indexes
```

**tripsys/.htaccess** content:

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /tripsys/
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
        # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
        # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
        # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

        ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
    </IfModule>
```

I've tried changing `/tripsys/` to `/tripsys/new_admin` in
   `/tripsys/.htaccess`, but still getting a 404.

Comment: Have tried adjusting the `$application_folder` variable in `index.php` ?

Comment: @doitlikejustin: Hi, you're talking about `tripsys/index.php`?

Comment: Yeah (I think) the CI `index.php`. Where you can control your application environment, among other things like the `application` folder location.